# React: this.state disappears in for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I carry `this` into my `.map()` loop? It seems to disappear. :-(

I'm creating a "dynamic form" where the user can specify multiple lines of input for his form. I want to iterate over all items in `state.items[]` and build form input fields for them.

E.g the form starts with 'field' and 'autocomplete_from. The user can then click **add a new line** to get more rows in his form.

```
102     render: function() {
103       return (
104         <div>
105           {this.state.items.map(function(object, i){
106             return (
107               <div>
109                 <FieldName/>

110                 <strong> State.autocomplete_from:
                            {this.state.autocomplete_from} </strong>
                         //       ^^^ 
                         //   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

120                 <button onClick={this.newFieldEntry}>Create a new field</button>
121                 <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save and Continue</button>
122               </div>
123               );
124           })}
125         </div>
126       );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `.map` **this** does not refer to your component., there are several ways how you can solve this issue

1. Save `this` to variable

   ```
   render: function() {
     var _this = this;

     return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map(function(object, i){
          return (
            <div>
              <FieldName/>

              <strong> State.autocomplete_from:
                {_this.state.autocomplete_from} </strong>

              <button onClick={this.newFieldEntry}>Create a new field</button>
              <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save and Continue</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
   }
   ```
2. Set `this` for `.map` callback(*if you can't use `ES2015` features, this variant is prefered*)

   ```
   this.state.items.map(function (object, i) {
      // ....
   }, this);
   ```
3. use `arrow function`

   ```
   this.state.items.map((object, i) => {
      // ....
   })
   ```
4. use `.bind`

   ```
   this.state.items.map(function(object, i) {
      // ....
   }.bind(this))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! @omar-elawady, you're answer is correct too, but I'll mark this as the accepted as it's more detailed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

second argument for iterative method such as `map` and `filter` is `this` object

so you can use it as follows:

`this.state.items.map(yourfunction,this)`

Comment: Should update the map call to only have one comma. Most people should pick up that this is will throw an error (since this should be the second argument), but it's probably good in case someone comes along who doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function. This is set to the global object unless it's a member method you are invoking or you are invoking with either `.call` or `.apply` which you can't in your case.

or in other words you can't close over `this` you can however closer over a standard variable to which you have assigned this. So in general if you have a function nested inside another funtion and you wish to refere to this do:

```
function outer(){
   var _this = this;
   someThingThatAcceptsACallback(function(){
      console.log(_this.state);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) or another modern EcmaScript6->JS5 compiler, you can use a simpler syntax for preserving the context of the outer context:

```
{
     this.state.items.map((object, i) => {
         return ( <div>
              <strong> State.autocomplete_from:
                  {this.state.autocomplete_from} 
              </strong>
              /*.... your code ...*/ </div>); 
     });
}
```

By using the arrow function syntax, the `this` context is bound automatically within the contained function, so you can use `this` as you already were and you don't need to do anything special in your code.