# React Native - accessing component state variables within map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to access my component's state attributes within a map function. I bind my renderInputControl function and am utilizing ES6 syntax to map across my inputs. I also placed a debugger outside of my map function and am able to access my state, but when placing the debugger inside the map function, I get an undefined error and lost scope. Am I incorrectly binding my function?

```
constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      currentSelection: '',
      currentInputValue: '',
    }

    this.renderInputControl = this.renderInputControl.bind(this)
    this.handleOnPress = this.handleOnPress.bind(this)
  }

renderInputControl() {
    // debugger
    return this.props.input.options_labels_en.map((label, index) => {
      let numberSign = '  '
      if (input.show_points == true) {
        if (optionValues[index] > 0) {
          numberSign = '+'
        } else if (optionValues[index] < 0) {
          numberSign = ''
        }
      }
      // debugger
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(input.name, label, optionValues[index])}
          key={index}
          >
          <View style={this.state.currentSelection == label ? test.selectedInputControl : test.unselectedInputControl}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={[{flex: 9}, this.state.currentSelection == label ? test.selectedText : test.unselectedText]}>{label}</Text>
              <Text style={[{flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center'}, this.state.currentSelection == label ? test.selectedText : test.unselectedText]}>{`${numberSign}${optionValues[index]}`}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      )
    })
  }
```

Comment: map and this.state problems is addressed really well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517715/react-this-state-disappears-in-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to do:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //your code
}
```

otherwise `this.props` will be undefined

Comment: I can see that passing in props to constructor will help with this.props, but my issue is with this.state being undefined.